# Adding a node containing multi-digit number at the nth position in a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have written a code for inserting a node at nth position.
When a user inputs 1 digit number in a node then it works perfectly but when user inputs equal to or more than two digit numbers then its keep on printing the last node only in infinite loop.

I couldn't figure out what's went wrong. My code is below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct st
{
    int roll;
    char name[20];
    struct st *next;
};

void add_middle(struct st **ptr)
{
    struct st *temp,*temp1;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct st ));
    printf("netre ur name\n");
    scanf("%s",temp->name);
    printf("enter ur roll\n");
    scanf("%d",&(temp->roll));

    if((*ptr==NULL)||(temp->roll<(*ptr)->roll))
    {
        temp->next=*ptr;
        *ptr=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp1=*ptr;
        while(temp1)
        {
            if((temp1->next==NULL)||(temp1->next->roll>temp->roll))
            {
                temp1->next=temp;
                temp->next=temp1->next;
                break;
            }
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }

    }
}

void display(struct st *ptr)
{
    while(ptr)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n",ptr->name,ptr->roll);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}

main()
{
    struct st *headptr=0;
    add_middle(&headptr);`
        add_middle(&headptr);
    add_middle(&headptr);
    display(headptr);
}
```

Comment: I assume you have a mistake in your code at:       `add_middle(&headptr);\``? Note the `\`` at the end of that line.

Comment: The lack of input validation not withstanding, you can make this considerably easier on yourself if you utilize that pointer-to-pointer for what it does best; [see example](http://pastebin.com/TGWz3W9C). Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: I would expect the code to look at each existing node starting at the head, if not out of nodes, compare existing node to the new node otherwise only update existing code.next with ptr to new node and new node.next = null.  If new node greater than existing node, update 2 next pointers (existing node to new node and new node to prior existing node.  As a suggestion, names like temp and temp1 are very confusing.  Much better to name them in a way related to their actual content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what happens when you insert the new node:

```
temp1->next = temp;
temp->next = temp1->next;
```

This will make the previous node (`temp1`) point to the new node, which is good. It will then have the new node (`temp`) point to itself (`temp1->next == temp`), which is bad.

**To fix this**, you can just swap those two lines. That is:

```
if ((temp1->next==NULL) || (temp1->next->roll > temp->roll)) {
    temp->next = temp1->next;
    temp1->next = temp;
    break;
}
```

Additionally, this could be much clearer if you used better variable names:

- `temp1` becomes `previousNode`
- `temp` becomes `newNode`